# "expected nested-name-specifier" error when compiling function template

Tags: c++

```
template <size_t B>        
void part(typename vector<bitset<B> > &partions)
```

I just want to pass in a vector consisting of bitset, but want this function to work for any kind of bitset. I am not good at using template

Comment: Can you share the template instantiation line of code also ?

Comment: I seems to have made a stupid mistake. The 'typename' should be added in function body when I call 'vector<bitset<B> >::iterator', NOT in the function paramters. Thanks all of you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template <size_t B>        
void part(vector<bitset<B> > &partions)
```

This should work